# Selected item in ListView hides JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx, hide

I have a **ListView** and I add **BorderPane elements** with some content.

---

When I select one item, it hides.

How can I fix this?

[The white item is the selected item. Is hidden.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la6kS.png)

I have no CSS for nothing in the listView

> UPDATE:

*BorderPane content*

```
public BorderPane getUserBox()
{
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

    HBox mainPane = new HBox();


    mainPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.prefWidthProperty());
    mainPane.minWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.minWidthProperty());
    mainPane.maxWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.maxWidthProperty());

    ImageView image = new ImageView(Images.CLOSE_ICON);

    Label nick = new Label("  Name");
    Label text = new Label("  Text ");

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(nick, text);

    Label time = new Label("   4.06.2016");

    mainPane.getChildren().addAll(image, vBox, time);

    borderPane.getStyleClass().add("userBox");

    borderPane.setCenter(mainPane);

    return borderPane;
}
```

*Adding the borderPane*

```
    UserBox userBox = new UserBox();

    ObservableList<BorderPane> items =FXCollections.observableArrayList (
    userBox.getUserBox(), userBox.getUserBox(), userBox.getUserBox(),    userBox.getUserBox());

    listUsersBox.setItems(items);
```

*I only have this css in the borderPane*

```css
.userBox {

    -fx-background-color: green;

}
```

Comment: How do you expect from us to help to find out what's wrong with your CSS/code if you don't actually post your CSS and Java code?

Comment: Why did you need some code, is just one Node (BorderPane), adding into a ListView. This code is irrelevant for the problem. At least i think so.
I update with the code.

Comment: How on earth is the code irrelevant for the problem? What do you think is causing the problem if it's not errors in your code? Create a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Ok i accept that i was wrong, the code is needed. But in this case is only adding a node to listView, the example that i added is a new program. Just a ListView, the getUserBox in an empty class, and use the method  to add elements in ListView.
And only the green CSS.

Comment: OK, sorry then and thanks for dedicate some time to guide me.
Sorry if i angry you a bit.

I will revise other parts of code, but the rest of the code is just one apart Decorator class.

Comment: Okay, so as the code is always relevant, based on your source I was able to form an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so when working with a `ListView` you shall not place graphical elements directly into the `ListView`, rather you shall use [setCellFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#setCellFactory%28javafx.util.Callback%29) to tell the `ListView` how to display elements.

> **Customizing ListView Visuals**
>
> The visuals of the ListView can be entirely customized by replacing
>   the default cell factory. A cell factory is used to generate ListCell
>   instances, which are used to represent an item in the ListView. See
>   the Cell class documentation for a more complete description of how to
>   write custom Cells.

As data source you shall have a data model, that fills the graphical representation with some real information.

In the following example I have created a `User` class, which is the model for one single element in the list view (the listview displays users). Then I have used the mentioned method to create a GUI layout for each user (note that you don't even need the `BorderPane` as you have filled only the center).

**Example**

*User.java*

```
public class User {

    private StringProperty nick = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private ObjectProperty<Date> time = new SimpleObjectProperty<Date>();

    public StringProperty nickProperty(){ return nick;}
    public StringProperty textProperty(){ return text;}
    public ObjectProperty<Date> timeProperty(){ return time;}

    public User(String nick, String text, Date time){

        this.nick.set(nick);
        this.text.set(text);
        this.time.set(time);
    }
}
```

*Main.java*

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());


            ListView<User> listView = new ListView<User>();

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            ObservableList<User> users = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            users.addAll(new User("Bruce", "Is strong", sdf.parse("24/12/1975")),
                    new User("Claire", "Is clever", sdf.parse("02/01/1986")), 
                    new User("Bale", "Is funny", sdf.parse("03/01/1989")));

            listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<User>, ListCell<User>>() {

                @Override
                public ListCell<User> call(ListView<User> param) {
                    return new ListCell<User>(){

                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(User item, boolean empty) {

                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if(item != null){

                                HBox mainPane = new HBox();
                                ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("close_icon.png").toExternalForm(),
                                        20, 20, true, true));

                                Label nick = new Label(item.nickProperty().get());
                                Label text = new Label(item.textProperty().get());

                                VBox vBox = new VBox();
                                vBox.getChildren().addAll(nick, text);

                                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                                Label time = new Label(dateFormat.format(item.timeProperty().get()));

                                mainPane.getChildren().addAll(image, vBox, time);

                                setGraphic(mainPane);

                            }
                        }

                    };
                }
            });

            listView.setItems(users);

            root.setCenter(listView);


            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**This code produces the following:**

[image]

I would highly recommend to inform yourself about how to work with JavaFX controls that has a data model like ListView, TableView.

Good place to start learning: [Using JavaFX UI Controls: ListVew](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm)

Comment: A lot of thanks for the answer. I will use the example for revise my code, and use the cellFacory. With your example i am sure that i will fix my problem.